# Rails jquery auto complete with multi select values

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using the jquery auto complete with multiple select values. There it appends a "," to the last element. I need to remove the "," from the last value. But I need the values in comma seperated format.

How to remove the "," .

Comment: can u show the looping or any code u r adding , to the end of each word?

Comment: add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push( "" );
                    this.value = terms.join( ", " );
                    return false;
                }
            });